# Installing an old platform of the Android SDK

Tags: android

I'm trying to run [FlowDroid](https://blogs.uni-paderborn.de/sse/tools/flowdroid/) on an old malware sample and it gives me the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: error: target android.jar (/Users/ThomasVanhelden/android/Android-SDK/platforms/android-3/android.jar) does not exist
```

I assume the error says that I don't have the Android SDK platform of level 3. To solve this I've tried to install it using the SDK manager. The GUI version doesn't show any API version below 7. When I run the non-GUI version via my command-line, API 3 is listed as number 152:

```
149- Google APIs, Android API 6, revision 1 (Obsolete)
150- Google APIs, Android API 5, revision 1 (Obsolete)
151- Google APIs, Android API 4, revision 2 (Obsolete)
152- Google APIs, Android API 3, revision 3 (Obsolete)
153- Sources for Android SDK, API 24, revision 1
154- Sources for Android SDK, API 23, revision 1
```

But I can't get it to install. Trying to install it via `android update sdk -u -a -t 152` gives me the following output:

```
Installing Archives:
  Preparing to install archives
  Skipping 'Google APIs, Android API 3, revision 3 (Obsolete)'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android 1.5, API 3, revision 4 (Obsolete)' which was not installed.
  Done. Nothing was installed.
```

Am I doing something wrong? Is there any place I can download API 3?

Comment: have you tried to install the SDK API 3 before?

Comment: You don't get it from someone who still has it you can simply copy the oldest available API (currently 9?) to that directory. And the jar only contains method stubs the effect should be negligible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way (that I know of) to install an obsolete Android API. 
You can manually create a folder called `android-3` in the platforms directory of your Android-SDK. Then just copy the contents of your current SDK into that folder. This is most likely to solve the problem if you use an older (but still available) SDK to copy into `android-3`.